# Is there a simple way to get started, and learn as I go? I can't afford up-front time investment

Tags: installing

I have made a few attempts to begin writing with TEX or LATEX on a couple of MS Windows machines and one Ubuntu box I no longer own. ( I currently have Mint, though, and MS Windows, and I'm thinking of getting a Mac.) Those last few times, I was recommended to install a variety of programs, and they did not seem to work well with each other.

Each time, after about a week of work, I would end up with a saved document that had one line on it that didn't look like what I wanted. To make a long question short(er), out of all the options, is there anything close to my hopes of finding the following: about half an hour to install not too many executables, and with which I can get to writing some equations within 24 hours? (Also, on a crappy old machine, what's the way to go?)

Comment: In ubuntu is easy install TexLive with the program install-tl-ubuntu. On the other hand, there is online editor https://es.sharelatex.com/ (in spanish) and you can save projects (you will need an account in this website)

Comment: If you are going to use a mac, try TexPad. I only started 3 years ago and it really helped me a lot.

Comment: The online sites (ShareLaTeX and Overleaf) avoid installation problems so you can start immediately. Equations are made easier with [WebEquation](http://webdemo.myscript.com/#/demo/equation)--just write what you want and see the latex code (copy/paste between $ signs to get the formula).

Comment: Just install texlive and avoid installing that variety of stuff you have been recommended and that didn't seem to work well with each other.

We don't know what stuff that was, but chances are when they are more mature and work well with other stuff they will be included in texlive.

Comment: "Each time, after about a week of work, I would end up with a saved document that had one line on it that didn't look like what I wanted." -- when my PhD advisor gave up on Word for his students' thesis/dissertation writing, he had them all write up increasingly-complex papers for class assignments. By the end of the class, they were relatively comfortable with LaTeX, at least enough to use the university's thesis template correctly. Given that, I'd focus on content creation before formatting details. Besides, much of what you might want to replicate from Word may be bad typography anyway.